# How to implement LDAP authentication in a C project

Tags: authentication, ldap

I have a application written in C and the current authentication is using PAM authentication plugin and I would like to replace it with LDAP authentication. But I don't really know how to do it. I would like a C tutorial about integrating LDAP in an application and a good reference to the ldap protocol how it works... 
Thank you very much :).